# Problem with implementation with the 100 doors Problem

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

So far I got this code and its working perfectly, but my prof wants me to add something more.

```py
doors = [False] * 100
for i in range(100):
   for j in range(i, 100, i+1):
       doors[j] = not doors[j]
   print("Door %d:" % (i+1), 'open' if doors[i] else 'close')`
```

Implementation:
To make the task easier, its results verifiable, and the script more versatile, you
decide to compartmentalize the task into three functions and introduce a few
variables:

**create(num)** creates an appropriate data structure with one parameter – num:
number of elements to be created with with initial values. It returns this
data structure.

**switch(doors, nths)** switches the lock status of the doors represented in the
data structure doors. Variable nths contains several numbers n– each
number n determines that every nth door’s lock status is to be switched (in
the example above this would be 2, 3, 4, 5, …).

**results(doors, val)** returns the door number of each door in the data structure doors that currently has the value val.

thanks for every hint I get!

Comment: I'd start by creating three functions called `create`, `switch` and `results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be something like you want:

```
def create(num):
    doors = [False] * num
    return doors

def switch(doors, nths):
    for n in nths:
        if not doors[n-1]:
            doors[n-1] = True
        else:
            doors[n-1] = False
    return doors

def results(doors, val):
    for i,d in enumerate(doors):
        print("Door %d:" % (i+1), 'open' if doors[i] != val else 'close')


my_doors = create(100)
my_doors = switch(my_doors, [2, 3, 4, 5])
results(my_doors, False)
```

It gives the output:

```
Door 1: close
Door 2: open
Door 3: open
Door 4: open
Door 5: open
Door 6: close
Door 7: close
...
Door 100: close
```